# How do I determine exactly which method throws this error: Javascript: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to upgrade to JQuery 1.10 from a much older version. Unfortunately, upgrading causes previously working code to fail with this error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

The unfortunate part of this is that the message does not tell me exactly which method or property is causing this error.

As an example, I am getting this error trying to call a dialog to show:

```
$('#RepSearchDialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      width: 1050,
      height: 500,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Rep Search',
      modal: true,
      open: function () {
        ClearRepSearchCriteriaFields();
        ClearRepSearchResults();
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
        $('#RepSearchStoreId').val($('#StoreId').val());
        $('#RepSearchStoreId').focus();
        $('input[name="RepSearchOption"]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
        $('input[name="RepSearchOption"]')[4].checked = true;

        window.RepSearchDialog_SearchForReps();
      }
    });
```

It's not obvious to me which property or method call is causing the dialog call to fail. How can I get information on the exact property or method that is causing this to fail?

This is making upgrading very, very painful.

Comment: Press F12 and use the built-in debugging console to get down to a linenumber.

Comment: Kevin, it just points me right to the line of code I listed above. Then it says, "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'" Huh? So why doesn't .dialog() work anymore? WTF?

Comment: Something is interfering with `$("#RepSearchDialog")` returning a proper jQuery object. Either that, or you're not loading jQuery UI successfully (maybe you need to upgrade it as well).

Comment: *"the line of code I listed above"* I see 19 lines of code, not one... am i missing something? does changing to `$('#RepSearchDialog').dialog()` change the error?

Comment: @Barmar I upgraded jquery.ui but apparently I haven't done it correctly. I had to add a ref to jquery.ui.dialog.js. Now I get another error: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'widget' jquery.ui.dialog.js:38. I've added the ref to widget but still errors. this is painful.

Comment: are you loading in jquery.ui AFTER the "regular" jquery lib ?

Comment: are you loading an updated version of jQuery UI that supports jQuery 1.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've downloaded jQueryUI piecewise and missed some of the pieces. Try pulling from the CDN and see if that fixes the issue:

```
// pull from MS' CDN
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If that solves it, then either pull the complete library down to load locally, or use the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) to get just the parts you need (and don't uncheck dependencies!)

Comment: That seems to be the case. I downloaded from the JQuery UI site. There's about 20+ files and apparently I need to include a ref to each "widget" I want to use now instead of simply being able to add a ref to a single .ui.js file. I got an error for the DatePicker first, then the Dialog, then a Button... I have one more error I don't quite understand when the page loads for the first time, but the main issues seems solved by including refs to all the controls. Thanks.

Comment: Well, with the download builder, when you select just the ones you need, it should still build a jQuery.ui.js file with only the widgets you've selected. For example, I have a `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js` file in one of my projects that contains only `datepicker` and `autocomplete`.